# How can a already selected column be stored as a range object?

Tags: excel, vba

Getting a run time error: Object required. Need help with the syntax.

```
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
```

Comment: Just remove the .Select

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: But try avoid using `.Select`. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).